# Using multiple functions to mimic a formula?

Tags: python, function, variables

I am attempting to write a filenamed bmr.py with a function named st_jeor which, if given (mass, height, age, sex), returns Mifflin St Jeor estimate of the basal metabolic rate, an estimate of the Calories consumed to keep the body alive. Assume mass is given in kilograms, height in centimeters, age in years, and sex is either "male" or "female".

S is +5 if sex is "male" and −161 if it is "female"; m, h, and a represent mass, height, and age respectively.[image]

Here is what I started with:

```
def st_jeor(mass, height, age, sex):
    global mass
    global height
    global age
    mass = (10.00*mass/1
    height =
    age =

    def sex(s):
        if sex == 'male':
            return 5
        else:
            return -161
```

Anyone have suggestions on what route I should be taking? Think I am confusing myself.

Comment: why did you stop going? you had a good start there..

Comment: I would avoid global variables if possible. But just keep going till you break something, then come post the issue if needed

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: also you can avoid division if units are [`kg`, `cm`, `year`], because `x / 1 = x`, so function looks: `10.0*m + 6.25*h - 5.0*a + s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have defined function `st_jeor` that takes necessary arguments to use this formula. It's ok. 
You don't have to use `global` in this case. 
You don't have to convert arguments if you pass them using correct units.

You just write formula using given arguments.

```
def st_jeor(mass, height, age, sex):
    # it's better to use ternary operator in this case
    sex = 5 if sex == 'male' else -161
    # just put given parameters and calculate result
    p = 10 * mass + 6.25 * height - 5.0 * age + sex
    return p
```

Ternary operator

```
sex = 5 if sex == 'male' else -161
```

is equivalent to

```
if sex == 'male':
    sex = 5
else:
    sex = -161
```

Comment: i would recommend to do `sex = 5 if sex.lower() == 'male' else -161`

Comment: could you put that line sex = 5 if sex=="male" else -161 into an else/if format? I do not understand how that single line works.

Comment: @nikitaZakharov

Comment: Check my answer